# Slim Post Request Returns 404 error on Remote server

Tags: php, post, http-post, slim, remote-server

I am working on an API for my iOS app. API interact with database via webservice. API is written with help of Slim framework in php. I tested api on local server and all is working fine. On uploading them to live server I noticed that all request with **GET** method still work but request with **POST** does not work on remote server, and always return **404 Page not found** error. I just tested one api converting from **POST** to **GET** and it worked as expected. Below is my code for Slim post request.

```
\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader(); 
$app = new \Slim\Slim();
$app->post('/forgotPassword', function() use ($app){

            verifyRequiredParams(array('email'));
            $response = array();
            // reading post params
            $email = $app->request->post('email');

            $db = new DbHandler();
            $res = $db->forgotPassword($email);

        if ($R = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
             $response["error"] = false;
            $response["message"] = "Password reset instructions have been sent to your email";
        } else {
            $response["error"] = True;
            $response["message"] = "error";
        }

            echoRespnse(201, $response);
        });

$app->run();
```

Comment: Try **$email = $app->request->getParam('email');**

Comment: Request does not reach that point. It send 404 error even before that

Comment: Would you write your html form ?

Comment: there is no html form, just sending data via "Postman (a rest api application)".

Comment: I found that: "For a POST path in Slim, you have to POST a request to /forgotPassword/. Loading that URL in a browser tab (a GET request) won't invoke the callback function." So try to use **map** function as in the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

It could be an alternative to use map function instead of post :

```
$app->map(['GET', 'POST'],'/email', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
    if ($request->isPost())
        //enter code here
    });
```

Comment: Try to just var_dump($_POST); do you see any results ?